# Move form with BorderStyle bsNONE?

Tags: macos, delphi, delphi-xe2, firemonkey

How to move form if the `BorderStyle` is set to `bsNONE` for border style?
in firemonkey MAC OS X

Answer (score 1):

Without the form header, you'll need to roll your own method for the user to move the form.

To move the form in code, you can set the form's Left and Top properties.

Comment: I want to move form such as form header method . could you write an example method

Comment: @user1581036, I don't think you've provided enough details to write a method. Move it how?

Answer (score 0):

There is how you do it in HD FireMonkey XE4 Desktop application:

```
var
Form1: TForm1;
isDraging: boolean;
X0, Y0: single;

implementation

{$R *.fmx}

procedure TForm1.FormMouseDown(Sender: TObject; Button: TMouseButton;
  Shift: TShiftState; X, Y: Single);
begin
  isDraging := True;
  X0 := X;
  Y0 := Y;
end;

procedure TForm1.FormMouseMove(Sender: TObject; Shift: TShiftState;
  X, Y: Single);
begin
  if isDraging then
  begin
    Form1.Left := Trunc(Form1.Left + X - X0);
    Form1.Top := Trunc(Form1.Top + Y - Y0);
  end;
end;

procedure TForm1.FormMouseUp(Sender: TObject; Button: TMouseButton;
  Shift: TShiftState; X, Y: Single);
begin
  isDraging := False;
end;
```

Tested and works on Windows 7 and Mac OS X Lion.